# passing dataframe from outside function to server in shiny app

Tags: r, function, dataframe, shiny, shinyapps

I want to send my [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) from function `summ()` to server function. I am performing all operations in `summ()` function{operationsi am not showing} and at last `dataframes` is prepared. In server, I want to plot two separate graphs using those dataframes named `df` and `df1`.
Can anybody help me how to send these dataframes from `summ` function into [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny).

```
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)
 ui<-fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput(inputId = "Y",label = "Price", value = 2, min =1,max = 6),
  sliderInput(inputId = "d_km",label = "Distance", value = 5, min =1,max = 20),
  sliderInput(inputId = "fact",label = "Multiplication", value = 2, min =1,max = 5),
  actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Simulate")
),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("X"),
  plotOutput("HH")


    )

 )
)

  summ<-function(Y,d_km,fact)
{

  ### code   ###
 df <- data.frame("x"=x,"y1"=y1,"y2"=y2)
 df1<- data.frame("obj"=obj_vector)

returns <- list(plot = df, plots=df1)

}
 server<-function(input, output,session){
 default_list <- list(plot = df, plots=df1)

  # daf <- data.frame()
  rv<-reactiveValues(data=default_list)
  rv$data <- reactive(summ (input$Y, input$d_km, input$fact))

  frame <- eventReactive(input$button, {
returned <- rv$data()
cost <- returned$plot
 })

  frame1 <- eventReactive(input$button, {
returned <- rv$data()
coost <- returned$plots
 })


   output$X <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(frame(), aes(x)) +                    # basic graphical object
  geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="red") +  # first layer
  geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="green")+
  xlab("Bag_no.")+ylab("Price in USD")+
  geom_text(aes(y=y1,label=y1),size=3,angle=45)
  })

  output$HH <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(frame1(),aes(x=seq(1,runs,1),y=obj_vector))+geom_line(colour="blue")+
    xlab("Simulation_run")+ylab("Objective_value")
   # grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
 })
 }
   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your `server` you define `default_list` using `df` and `df1` which are not defined not before nor after in your global or server's local environments. Also you don't actualy use `default_list` even after assigning it to `rv` using `reactiveValues()`, so I don't see the goal of `default_list` in your App. You can replace that one like following, if you still need it in your program:

```
default_list <- list(plot = c(), plots = c())
```

2. In server `frame` and `frame1` are functions and they are assumed to return smth.
   So you can change it like this:

```
frame <- eventReactive(input$button, {
  returned <- rv$data()
  cost <- returned$plot
  cost # <= Add This
})

frame1 <- eventReactive(input$button, {
  returned <- rv$data()
  coost <- returned$plots
  coost # <= And This
})
```

3. In `output$HH` visualization you use variable `runs` which is not defined anywhere in your App, you need to define it beforehand to use (maybe you have defined it in code that you don't show, but now it causes error).
4. Again in `output$HH` you use `y = object_vector`, but in `summ()` you assign it to `data.frame('obj' = object_vector)`, so you need to change your code like this:

Or in `summ()`:

```
data.frame('object_vector' = object_vector)
```

Either in `output$HH`:

```
y = obj
```